# Firebase - google signin loop

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

EDIT - the new code, everything is inside a function.

Im making a online game, and i want to use google signin with firebase. The problem is that when i open the website i go straight too google signin, but the signin process is inside a function that doesnt start anywhere.

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "#",
  authDomain: "#",
  databaseURL: "#",
  projectId: "#",
  storageBucket: "#",
  messagingSenderId: "#",
  appId: "#",
  measurementId: "#"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
// Initialize Firebase

// Google sign in - firebase
function signoutgg() {
    import { signOut } from "firebase/auth";

    signOut(auth).then(() => {
    // Sign-out successful.
    }).catch((error) => {
    // An error happened.
    });
}

function signingg() {
    import { GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";
    const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

    import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
    import { signInWithRedirect } from "firebase/auth";
    import { getRedirectResult } from "firebase/auth";

    const auth = getAuth();
    signInWithRedirect(auth, provider)
  .then((result) => {
    // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
    const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
    const token = credential.accessToken;
    // The signed-in user info.
    const user = result.user;
    // ...
  }).catch((error) => {
    // Handle Errors here.
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
    // The email of the user's account used.
    const email = error.email;
    // The AuthCredential type that was used.
    const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error);
    // ...
  });


    getRedirectResult(auth)
  .then((result) => {
    // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access Google APIs.
    const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
    const token = credential.accessToken;

    // The signed-in user info.
    const user = result.user;
  }).catch((error) => {
    // Handle Errors here.
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
    // The email of the user's account used.
    const email = error.email;
    // The AuthCredential type that was used.
    const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error);
    // ...
  });

  var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token

  import { signInWithCredential } from "firebase/auth";
    
    // Build Firebase credential with the Google ID token.
    const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(id_token);

    // Sign in with credential from the Google user.
    signInWithCredential(auth, credential).catch((error) => {
    // Handle Errors here.
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
    // The email of the user's account used.
    const email = error.email;
    // The AuthCredential type that was used.
    const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error);
    // ...
});
}
```

The bottom of body in index.html where I link to the scripts.

```
<script type="module" src="/node_modules/firebase/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="/node_modules/firebase/firebase-database.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="/node_modules/firebase/firebase-auth.js"></script>
```

I dont understand why the signin starts when its inside an function, I want to call that function when the user press "sign in with google".

I also get these warnings when i build the js with webpack.

```
WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
This can impact web performance.
Assets:
  bundle.js (1.59 MiB)

WARNING in entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.
Entrypoints:
  main (1.59 MiB)
      bundle.js


WARNING in webpack performance recommendations:
You can limit the size of your bundles by using import() or require.ensure to lazy load some parts of your application.
For more info visit https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/
```

Im using:

- Vanilla JS
- Node.js
- Webpack
- Firebase

Let me know if you need more information about the program.

This is the script for build. I use the regular "build".

```
    "build": "webpack --mode=production --node-env=production",
    "build:dev": "webpack --mode=development",
    "build:prod": "webpack --mode=production --node-env=production",
```

The only bad thing I know in my code is:

```
random = signingg.length;
```

The reason I have this is because I need to declare it somewhere. This is below all the other code. I know this is not a good thing to do..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out there was a problem with WebPack, when my JS got compiled, something happend so the functions ran everytime the script was loaded. I didnt figure out the problem with WebPack.

The script shoud work when everything is inside a function.

Answer (score 0):

`getRedirectResult` is an alternative to retrieving the OAuth token after the user sign-in success.

You should then use either of these methods and you can simply retrieve the sign in result calling only your `signingg` method and removing the `getRedirectResult` call chain.

Comment: I removed the `getRedirectResult`, then only made the "signingg" function, but it still goes straight too the google login.. A function should only execute the code inside when its called, but I have not called for it anywhere. I suspect it maybe the `import { signInWithRedirect } from "firebase/auth";`. I have never used imports before.

Comment: I cannot see how it would redirect to Google login page. Would you please update the post with caller as well? By the way, I thought you were copy / pasting all your sources at once and the file would not actually look like the one you posted. `import` statements are only allowed at the source top level. Use the `require` function to import your function on the fly.

Comment: I dont have a caller for the function... I updated the post. I followed the docs at https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin.